# grep for multiple patterns with end of line as a string

Tags: regex, bash, perl, shell, grep

I have multiple files in a directory.

Contents of all the files:

```
Client=WebsiteContent
Operation=Eligibility
EnvName=StoreWebsite
Program=DummyService
EOE
-----------------------------------------------
Client=WebsiteContent
Operation=Eligibility
Dummy=Hello
EnvName=StoreWebsite
Program=DummyService
Metric=Helloworld
EOE
-----------------------------------------------
```

`grep` usually works line by line. Instead I want to consider the string `EOE` as the [input record separator](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) so that I can grep for multiple fields.

Example:

I want to grep for different 'Program' where the `Client` attribute contains `WebsiteContent` and the `Operation` attribute contains `Eligibility`.

Output:

```
Program=Dummy
Program=Something
Program=Hello
```

EDIT:

I do this in Perl using

```
zcat * | perl -ne '$/="EOE"; next unless /Client=WebsiteContent/ && Operation=Eligibility/; print $_;' | grep 'Program=.*'
```

The above command gives me the results. But, I want to do this using shell (`grep`, `awk`, `sed` etc.)

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is the problem, What have you tried so far? Show us the code.

Comment: I have a question, where's your code?

Comment: Added the code that I use

Comment: why use many processes `grep`, `awk`, `sed` when this can be done by one. `perl` has the advantage of being more stable, regarding syntax, than unix tools which can differ depending version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run that though pipes with convert each record to a line with colons (or some other unused character) delimiting fields.  Temporarily, you will need another unused character (such as a semicolon) to delimit records:

```
cat input_file.txt | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/---:/---;/' | tr ';' '\n'
```

You can then pipe the results of that through `grep`:

```
| grep 'Client=WebsiteContent' | grep 'Operation=Eligibility'
```

Then pipe the results of that back through `tr`:

```
| tr ':' '\n'
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks @Jack

Answer (score 2):

First off - don't try and coerce this into a one liner. It's not all that useful. Especially if you're trying to daisy chain shell commands.

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = 'EOE'; 
while ( <> ) { 
   my %record = m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
   print $record{'Program'},"\n";
}
```

This uses key-value matching into a hash, and extracts a named value.

Which you can then extend:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = 'EOE';
while (<>) {
   my %record = m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g;
   if (   $record{'Operation'} eq "Eligibility"
      and $record{'Client'} eq "WebsiteContent" )
   {
      print $record{'Program'}, "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I love this answer pretty much. If no answers with shell, I'll up vote and mark it as right and close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The `$/="EOE"` must be in `BEGIN` otherwise there's a risk of missing one match.

The grep process is useless it can be done in perl process.

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="\nEOE\n"} next unless /Client=WebsiteContent/ && /Operation=Eligibility/; /Program=.*/ && print "$&\n";'
```

Otherwise to do it only with unix tools and pipelines

```
...| tr '\n' , | sed 's/,EOE,/\n/g' | grep Client=WebsiteContent | grep Operation=Eligibility | tr , '\n' | grep Program=
```